# Signout Then Reload Page Automatic Sign In

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

On my multi-page HTML website (hosted by Firebase), I have a sign in/out button. Whenever I press sign out, the sign out button becomes the sign in button, thanks to my CSS, and the console reports "user not logged in".

However, when I reload the page or navigate to a different one (Ctrl+R and Ctrl+Shift+R make no difference), the sign out button reappears, and the console reports "user logged in", as if the server doesn't remember the user should be signed out, and not automatically signed in after the page reloads.

Here's what I use for sign in. Note that `setButtons()` is my code to change the CSS to show what button I need to. `gLogin()` is called when the Sign In button is pressed, and `gLogout` is called when the Sign Out button is pressed.

```
var signedIn;
var curUser = null;

function updateUser(user)
{
    if (user) {
        curUser = user;
        signedIn = true;
        console.log("User is logged in");
        // User is signed in.
    } else {
        curUser = null;
        signedIn = false;
        console.log("User is not logged in");
        // No user is signed in.
    }
    setButtons(signedIn);
}

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(updateUser);

function gLogin() {
    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(gProvider).then(function (result) {       
    var token = result.credential.accessToken; 
    var user = result.user;
    signedIn = true;
    location.reload(true);
  }).catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
  });
}

function gLogout() {
    firebase.auth().signOut().then(function () {
        signedIn = false;
        updateUser(null);
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Comment: Make sure you are not double including the firebase JS library (for example, don't include firebase.js and firebase-auth.js at the same time). This is known to cause issues like this, where a signed out user is signed in again.

Comment: @bojeil ah, I didn't know this. So I should just include firebase-auth.js instead? Thanks!

Comment: If you include firebase.js, don't include firebase-auth.js. If you include firebase-auth.js, make sure firebase-app.js is included (you can include other stuff you need too like firebase-database.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out: Apparently, the issue was that I didn't set a default auth persistence state. From what I understand, this meant that persistence would have undocumented behavior. Here's what I added to each of my pages' scripts:

```
firebase.auth()
.setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION)
.then(function() {
    console.log("Persistence set");
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```